# How can I share or distribute my Cordova/PhoneGap App with phone hotspot, public Wi-Fi or Bluetooth

Tags: android, cordova, socket.io, ionic-framework, wifi-direct

I use stackoverflow for long time but this is my first question for the community. I googled this question but I could n’t find any answer on it.

I am developing an Event app for all major platforms like Android, IOS, and Windows. It hast its own features like schedule, checking in, connecting with people and chat with them, voting or polling, commenting….

I can distribute my app through Apple stores, Google Play, Windows store by publishing on them but I want users to share this app without stores. There are different reason for this like

1. They don’t have Google , Apple or Windows account or they don’t what
   to use that
2. There is no internet connection or it is too expensive to download
   my app.
3. Or they don’t know how to use App store to install.

So I came up with idea that why not they share my app through Wi-Fi or Bluetooth by creating there hotspot or by joining public hotspot.

So my question is:

1. How to create a hotspot using cordova/phonegap
2. Pack my app to be shared via Wi-Fi or Bluetooth
3. Serve my app via http to be accessed by phone who shared with my network here I found a plugin CorHttpd https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-httpd but I am not sure
4. Share my app via Bluetooth.

There is an app called xender http://www.xender.com/

> Xender – A cross-platform file transfer and sharing app. Sharing
>   files, photos, music, videos, contacts, even apps without mobile data
>   usage, and support to transfer to Android, iOS, WP, and PC/Mac.

This app share itself through Wi-Fi, Bluetooth or form stores.

**Is it possible to do that with Cordova/PhoneGap?**

By doing this I can maximize my app distribution through Apple stores, Google Play, Windows store + **[ Sideload with Wi-Fi and Bluetooth  ]**

I really need this because I am working on event app and people come to event without knowing there is an app for that event and they want to install this app at that moment. So I have to make it available with all channel

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Android Devices

On Android phones it is definitely possible to bluetooth over a file (say your application APK) and have the user manually find the file and open it on their device. As long as they had the "Unkown Sources" box checked in their security preferences then they would be able to install it. However, this process is rather lengthy and a hassle. As far as I know there is no other way to sideload an application as this would almost seem like overriding/hijacking the users phone and installing an application (which could be malicious).

Xender seems to simply just send files between devices, which would be the case here. If you look at the link you shared for their site and see the facebook application being sent over, its actually sending the facebook.apk file which the user would then have to open to install in on their Android device.

[Android Sideloading Bluetooth](http://www.guidingtech.com/10346/transfer-android-apps-between-phones-bluetooth/)

### iOS Devices

There is no way for you to sideload onto an iOS device, unless the device is jailbroken (or an Apple computer is available then sideloading via Xcode is possible) and which case the same type of method could be accomplished as the Android method above.

### Windows Devices

I have no idea if sideloading is possible or not on Windows Devices. From what I have read it seems that it is also restricted as in iOS's case.

### Wifi

It would be possible to send the file over wifi from one device to the other but if the users have access to wifi why not just have them install your application from the device store? I know you stated that perhaps they did not want to use their account but almost all phones these days require you to have an account if you plan on getting any application off the app store so if the user has a smart phone there is a good chance they have an account linked to their device. I do not see why someone would want to use your app (assuming its available for free since you're trying to sideload) and would refuse to use their account to download it.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25638335/how-to-transfer-files-between-android-devices-using-wifi-direct) should be useful for learning how to transfer files using wifi direct. This is only on android though as I have previously stated, Android seems to be the only operating system which you can *natively* install a sideloaded application.

### Conclusion

In the end the only device that seems able to do what you are trying would be Android devices in which you could potentially include your .apk file within your application's storage system and have an activity which sends this file over bluetooth or wifi.

Comment: Thank you @sargturner for your answer. I know IOS and Windows doesn’t allow to install app outside store but android allows you to install by enabling “Unknown Sources" on security setting. I really want to know is how to start Wi-Fi hotspot and send file via Wi-Fi or starting Bluetooth and send file to other phone  using **Cordova/PhoneGap** on xender you can send xender itself by creating a Wi-Fi hotspot and giving you ip (url address) like 192.168.43.27:1234/5 and any one how visit this link will download xender and can install the app to share other files.